# Too few arguments in call

Tags: c++

I am doing a project about mortage rates and i cant get the pow function to work right it keeps saying that i need more words im just trying to feel it up so it will let me post it:

```
double loanAmount = 0.0;
double annualIntrest = 0.0;
double loanDuration = 0.0;
double monthlyIncome = 0.0;
double payMent = 0.0;
double monthlyIntrest = 0.0;
double totalIntrest = 0.0;
double percentTotal = 0.0;
int const PERCENTAGE = 100;

// *** Your program goes here ***
printf("Enter the amount of the loan: $");
scanf("%lf", &loanAmount);
if (loanAmount > 0.0) {
    printf("Enter the annual interest rate (8.0 = 8.0%%): ");
    scanf("%lf", &annualIntrest);

    if ((annualIntrest >= 1.0) && (annualIntrest <= 20.0)) {
        printf("Enter the length of the loan (in years): ");
        scanf("%lf", &loanDuration);

        if ((loanDuration >= 1) && (loanDuration <= 30)) {
            printf("Enter your monthly gross income: $");
            scanf("%lf", &monthlyIncome);


            if (monthlyIncome > 0.0) {
                percentTotal = annualIntrest / PERCENTAGE;
                monthlyIntrest = (percentTotal / 12);
                payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest));
                pow(payMent, loanDuration);
                totalIntrest = loanDuration * payMent - loanAmount;


                printf("%.2lf\n", totalIntrest);
            }
            else {
                printf("Monthly income must be greater than $0.00");
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Loan duration must be between 1 year and 30 years");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Annual interest rate must be greater than 1.0%% and less than 20.0%%");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
else {
    printf("Loan amount must be greater than $0.00");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Assignment spec with formula to implement:

[image]

Comment: Could I entice you to [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]. It'd be something simple like your `main`, necessary include and the variable declarations, shouldn't be longer than 10 lines. Without this information we may just be guessing at what the issue is.

Comment: Hint; what is the expression `(1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest),-loanDuration)` supposed to do?

Comment: Usually, assignment inside the parameters of a function call are not advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break

```
pow(payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest),-loanDuration));
```

down a bit.

```
payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest),-loanDuration)
```

is one argument. The comma that should split it into two arguments is inside the brackets. Likely you meant

```
payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest)), -loanDuration
```

but even this is dodgy. You can put the assignment inside the function call, but why? You gain nothing and lose job opportunities for writing needlessly cryptic-as-smurf code.

The sane programmer writes

```
payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest));
pow(payMent,-loanDuration);
```

But

```
(1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest))
```

doesn't quite look right. It resolves down to `monthlyIntrest`, so it's very likely there is at least one additional transcription error typing in the formula.

Comment: thanks for the help the bad part is that im not even in programming im on the info tech side

Comment: for some reason the outcome is negative

Comment: All I can suggest is that you make sure the formula you're using is correct. Like I said in the answer, it doesn't look quite right.

Comment: dang ive looked over the formula and this stuff is stupid the formula is the one the teacher gave us hate programming

Comment: Can you add the given formula to your question? This would be one of the rare times when a picture might be a good idea. I don't know how well stack overflow handles the math lingo used for format math formulas.

Comment: Locked down, and I don't think it's in your best interests to share your username and password here. See if you can copy and and paste it into the question.

Comment: i go tit up there with all the code too

Comment: @CalebLeeCarey Note that in the formula only `1+r` is taken to the `-n`th power. This suggests the formula should look more like `payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - pow(1 + monthlyIntrest,-loanDuration));`

Comment: Thanks man I’m going to try that I freaking suck at coding

Answer (score 1):

In your example,

> pow(payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest),-loanDuration));

`payMent` is assigned

```
loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest), -loanDuration
```

which evaluates to

```
-loanDuration
```

and effectively to

```
payMent = -loanDuration
```

which is then used as argument to `pow()`. Use Parantheses to seperate the assignment from the second parameter:

```
pow((payMent = loanAmount * monthlyIntrest / (1 - (1 + monthlyIntrest)),-loanDuration);
    ^                                                                 ^
```